# Magento 2.4.4 - Magento modules inside the vendor folder don't work

Tags: magento2, php, setup-upgrade, vendor

I'm trying to run the "setup:upgrade" command to register all magento modules but this error is presented:

"PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar not found"

I realized that Magento doesn't hear the modules which are inside the vendor/magento folder. It basically ignores the files that are inside the vendor folder.

Everything worked fine before, now it's like something went wrong. How can I solve it?

Comment: At fist get the status of your modules ,  by running`bin/magento module:status`. The modules gets inside the vendor directory in first place only if they have been installed using composer (unless it was hard-copied manually).